# RedirectView not using relative path for Location

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, reverse-proxy

I have a web service setup to redirect from the root ('/') to a page ('my/page.html').

So, `http://localhost:8080/` should redirect to `http://localhost:8080/my/page.html`.

Here is the code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
public RedirectView localRedirect()
{
    final RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
    redirectView.setContextRelative(true);
    redirectView.setUrl("/my/page.html");

    return redirectView;
}
```

My expectation is the redirect response will have its `location` header set to the relative path: `/my/page.html`. However, in actuality, it is set to the full path: `http://localhost/my/page.html`.

This is causing some issues, because this application is running in a Docker container which thinks it is serving port 80; you may have noticed that the full path dropped the `:8080` port specifier in the URL. The Docker container is running behind a reverse proxy, which maps requests to `8080` to the container. If the `location` header were relative and set to `/my/page.html`, the expectation is the browser client would use the correct hostname (`localhost:8080`), so it would be redirected by the reverse proxy to the correct page.

As you can see from my code, I tried setting the `ContextRelative` option in the `RedirectView` object to true. Is there something else I am missing here?

**EDIT**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
public void localRedirect(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND);
    response.setHeader("Location", "/my/page.html");
}
```

I have gotten my redirection to work using the above code. However, I am still curious if anyone knows of a way to accomplish the above with `RedirectView` and `RedirectStrategy` from Spring, I would be happy to accept that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of your code is correct because you are saying that your redirectview url have be relative on context, but it have be a valid url and for this reason spring built it as a url, /my/page.html is not a valid url. said that the problem is that you should configure the url rewriting in a full duplex way and resolve in the reverse proxy the problem, in fact for the code prespective if it run on a server that serve on the 80 port the code will map your url on 80 otherwise you should write your url by hand like below:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
public RedirectView localRedirect()
{
    final RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();

    redirectView.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/my/index.html");
    redirectView.setHosts();
    return redirectView;
}
```

I tried to run two instance of application on my pc one on 80 and another one on 8080 and the redirections works correctly

**Update:**

when you use RedirectView the redirection happen on server side with HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect call, of course if your server stay behind a reverse proxy your server side application can not know it.
When you useset Location Header in your controller it is a plain string do not pass from your servlet environment. The redirection happen in your browser that in this case recive a relative url because in your controller you set a plain string and your browser already know the server that is already proxed.

**Update2**
The core logic of RedirectView class is a protected method called sendRedirect(...).

```
/**
     * Send a redirect back to the HTTP client
     * @param request current HTTP request (allows for reacting to request method)
     * @param response current HTTP response (for sending response headers)
     * @param targetUrl the target URL to redirect to
     * @param http10Compatible whether to stay compatible with HTTP 1.0 clients
     * @throws IOException if thrown by response methods
     */
    protected void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            String targetUrl, boolean http10Compatible) throws IOException {

        String encodedURL = (isRemoteHost(targetUrl) ? targetUrl : response.encodeRedirectURL(targetUrl));
        if (http10Compatible) {
            HttpStatus attributeStatusCode = (HttpStatus) request.getAttribute(View.RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE);
            if (this.statusCode != null) {
                response.setStatus(this.statusCode.value());
                response.setHeader("Location", encodedURL);
            }
            else if (attributeStatusCode != null) {
                response.setStatus(attributeStatusCode.value());
                response.setHeader("Location", encodedURL);
            }
            else {
                // Send status code 302 by default.
                response.sendRedirect(encodedURL);
            }
        }
        else {
            HttpStatus statusCode = getHttp11StatusCode(request, response, targetUrl);
            response.setStatus(statusCode.value());
            response.setHeader("Location", encodedURL);
        }
    }
```

the method first retrieve the url and then if http10Compatible is true eventually will use the response.sendRedirect(encodedURL); otherwise just put the your relative url in the Location Header without pass for the servlet api. in your code you do not provide data for active the if condition that prevents the sendRedirect of Servlet api. This can explain why in your code you have problems. Of course in any other branch of code: http10Compatible at false and so on your code just put a string in Location header and it works because in your browser that will perform the redirect arrives a relative url.

For the question if this is a bug of Servlet API I can put the official interface code:

HttpServletResponse.java:

```
 /**
     * Sends a temporary redirect response to the client using the specified
     * redirect location URL. This method can accept relative URLs; the servlet
     * container must convert the relative URL to an absolute URL before sending
     * the response to the client. If the location is relative without a leading
     * '/' the container interprets it as relative to the current request URI.
     * If the location is relative with a leading '/' the container interprets
     * it as relative to the servlet container root.
     * <p>
     * If the response has already been committed, this method throws an
     * IllegalStateException. After using this method, the response should be
     * considered to be committed and should not be written to.
     *
     * @param location
     *            the redirect location URL
     * @exception IOException
     *                If an input or output exception occurs
     * @exception IllegalStateException
     *                If the response was committed or if a partial URL is given
     *                and cannot be converted into a valid URL
     */
    public void sendRedirect(String location) throws IOException;
```

you can read the snippet of comment:

```
This method can accept relative URLs; the servlet
     * container must convert the relative URL to an absolute URL before sending
     * the response to the client
```

Reading it I can say that it is not a bug but a feature of the servlet api, that however put the only server host that know, itself and for this reason it does not works whit a revers proxy.

I hope that this can explain well the problem.

Comment: See my edits above. I cannot pass specify the full host name. The host name would have to point to the reverse proxy, but I don't want this web service to have any knowledge of it.

Comment: So the answer, then, is that RedirectView calls `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect`, which is including the full host name. You mention that `sendRedirect` makes use of the servlet environment to explain why the full host name is included. I am understanding this correctly? I don't understand why that makes sense. Perhaps this deserves a separate question.

Comment: Interestingly, I have gotten RedirectView to work by disabling HTTP 1.0 compatibility, which changes the code path to set the Location header instead of using `sendRedirect`.

Comment: it is very interesting! but the your problem using RedirectView is basically that the url is composed on server side and then how built the location header will depends by servlet api. I debuged the spring code and i see that the url is relative for this reason I can say that the your problem is releted by the servletapi and disabling http1 compatibility can enforce this. using the location header written by heands works because the ocation header do not pass by servlet specific redirest logic

Comment: Thanks for the response! Would you consider this to be a bug in the servlet implementations then? I have seen this behavior with Tomcat and Jetty so far.

Comment: I update the my answer including official snippet of code in order to explain the strange bheaviour

Comment: sendRedirect() can support relative paths. But Tomcat has a setting (``useRelativeRedirects``) that determines whether ``org.apache.catalina.connector.Response`` will convert the location to an absolute URL. It will also do so with the scheme and port from the request, which seems be set by CoyoteAdapter. CoyoteAdapter sets the port to either 80/443, according to the scheme and if proxyPort is not set.

In the case of Spring Boot, we can set useRelativeRedirects with ``server.tomcat.use-relative-redirects``.